# DST transform in Matlab Vs FFTW3

Tags: matlab, octave, fftw

I am porting a Matlab/Octave code to C. One of the implementations I need to port is the DST transform.
In Matlab/Octave, this is done using

```
A =[0.00000   4.24264   5.65685   7.07107   8.48528   0.00000]
res = dst(A)
ans =
22.3599   -4.7499   -4.4287    2.9465   -6.8864    1.9383
```

In C, I have done what the FFTW3 documentation says:

```
n = 6;
fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_r2r_1d( n, in, out, FFTW_RODFT10, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute ( plan );
```

where `in` is the input array. The result of this is, `out`:

```
 42.588457
-9.899495
 0.000000
 2.449490
-11.411543
 5.656854
```

Why are those results so different? Any ideas of what I am doing wrong here, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for exactly the same tranform, you may try the `RODFT00` flag instead.

According to docs of fftw, matlab, octave, it seems to fit, except for a 2 factor. Output of fftw may be twice the one of matlab or octave.

http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/pde/ug/dst.html

http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/dst.html

http://www.fftw.org/doc/1d-Real_002dodd-DFTs-_0028DSTs_0029.html

Bye,

Comment: awesome! You are right, I was using the wrong transform

Answer (score 1):

tried this x=[                 0
  -0.041389004581424
  -0.049979175343607
  -0.057007496876302
  -0.062473969179509
  -0.066378592253228
  -0.068721366097459
  -0.069502290712203
  -0.068721366097459
  -0.066378592253228
  -0.062473969179509
  -0.057007496876302
  -0.049979175343607
  -0.041389004581424
   0.500000000000000
  -0.500000000000000]

matlab's dst gives : 
 dst(x)=[-0.524649937006448
  -0.208549082037091
   0.175438242940290
  -0.201365706563574
   0.122632326416342
   0.023410695189363
  -0.170916792532103
   0.404635063593086
  -0.557336293807673
   0.766827077578399
  -0.834391996423464
   0.916008576298954
  -0.836787527646708
   0.743037852780101
  -0.522660424688284
   0.285317021943821]

using FFTW with "FFTW_RODFT00" flag
gives 
[-1.0493
-0.417098
0.350876
-0.402731
0.245265
0.0468214
-0.341834
0.80927
-1.11467
1.53365
-1.66878
1.83202
-1.67358
1.48608
-1.04532
0.570634]

Basically a factor of two is the difference, even if one uses same flag